# Show this is a probability generator

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the operator defined on $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Z})$ (the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity) given by
$$\mathcal{L}f(k) = |k| \cdot (f(k+1)+f(k-1)-2f(k))$$

In order to show that this is the generator of a process, I need to verify the usual conditions. This was not a problem, but what is left now is to show that for all $\lambda>0$, the range of $(I-\lambda\mathcal{L})$ is $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Z})$. The author of the notes says this is clear, but I do not see it, after all $\mathcal{L}$ is unbounded. Does someone have a hint?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that $\ f\ $ "vanishing at infinity", which I originally took to be synonymous with $\ \lim_\limits{k\rightarrow\pm\infty} f(k)=0\ $, actually means "$\ f(k)\ne 0\ $ for only a finite number of $\ k\ $", and I think it's clear that if $\ f(k)\ $ is non-zero for only a finite number of $\ k\ $, then so is $\ (I-\lambda\mathcal{L})f\ $.

Comment: I just checked the notes and saw that I have a typo. It ist $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{Z})$. Sorry for the confusion! I will edit the question...

Comment: I don't think that makes any difference, but I think the problem may be in the interpretation of "vanishing at infinity".  l'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Vanishing at infinity in this case means that for any $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{x: \ |fx)|>\epsilon\}$ is compact

Comment: Compact with respect to which topology?   With respect to the discrete topology, a set is compact if and only if it's finite, so $\ \{\ x\ :\ |f(x)|>\epsilon\ \}\ $ is compact for every $\ \epsilon>0\ $ if and only if $\ \lim_\limits{|x|\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0\ $. I don't believe that's sufficient for the stated result to hold.

Comment: Yes, the limit on both sides should be zero

Comment: The problem is that if $\ f(k)=\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\ $ for $\ |k|\ge1\ $ and $\ g=(I-\lambda\mathcal{L})f\ $, with $\ \lambda>0\ $, then $\ \{\ x\ :\ |f(x)| >\epsilon\,\}\ $ is compact with respect to the discrete topology for every $\ \epsilon>0\ $, but $\ \{\ x\ :\ |g(x)| >\epsilon\,\}\ $ is *not* compact when $\ \epsilon=\lambda\ $, so the result that the OP is being asked to prove would not be true.  So for the result to be true using your definition of "vanishing at infinity" you'll need to choose something other than the discrete topology to provide your specification of compactness.

Comment: I have managed to solve my confusion: What the author of the notes really meant was that this is a pre-generator, i.e. we can find a dense subset (e.g. the space of functions with compact support) for which this holds (which it does)